# Is there an editor that can allow me to see code snippets with references and declaration?

Tags: editor, atom-editor

just like how in sublime / atom, you can view usage and declaration of a function, I want to be able to view the usage and declaration, not only as a file and a line number, but when I hover over it, it will also show the lines of context around the declaration and usage in a popup / hover window that I can copy paste from.

Answer (score 0):

Source Insight does what you want but a little bit pricy and windows only.

Comment: is it worth the 200 dollar individual license?

Comment: I use it since version 2, and yes it does worth it.